# What is the "at most" modifier for in 'truncate'?

Tags: truncate

The manual of [`truncate`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/truncate) shows I can add `<` for "at most".

What is this for?

It sounds like the default to me.

Comment: I have to say that I don't understand the use of this command, or the need for it. Why would you want to lose data, make something inoperative or add meaningless bytes? Perhaps that is why there are no accepted answers to the questions about it.

Comment: @Wastrel If you want to lose data, like by deleting a line in a text file, one way to go about it is to overwrite the line with the text following it, and then reduce the size of the file by the size of the line you deleted, so you don't have garbage at the end. `truncate` is how you reduce the size of the file. Being also able to increase the size is nice because it's immediate regardless of the size (you don't need to wait for actual bytes to be written) and the increased size basically doesn't occupy any space on your drive, because it's implemented as a hole in the file.

Comment: FI, it says (my emphasis) *"-s, --size=SIZE. use this SIZE ... SIZE may be (or may be an integer optionally followed by) one of following: KB 1000, K 1024, MB 1000*1000, M 1024*1024, and so on for G, T, P, E, Z, Y. ... SIZE may also be prefixed by one of the following modifying characters: '+' extend by, '-' reduce by,* ***'<' at most,*** *'>' at least, '/' round down to multiple of, '%' round up to multiple of."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without `<` `truncate` will add zerobytes to the end of the file if it is smaller until the size is reached.

So this example is probably what you want in most cases:

```
truncate -s '<1M' filename
```

this will keep only the first 1MB of the file.

To keep only the end of a file you can use `tail` instead:

```
tail -n 1000 filename > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename
```

Answer (score 10):

Let's start with two files,

- `1M.dat` - 1 MiB of data (generated with `truncate --size 1M 1M.dat`)
- `10M.dat` - 10 MiB of data (generated with `truncate --size 10M 10M.dat`)

First consider the command `truncate --size 5M {file}` applied to these two files. Although the second file will be truncated as expected, the first file will be *increased* in size to reach the desired 5 MiB file length.

Now consider the command `truncate --size '<5M' {file}` applied to the two files. The second file will still be truncated as expected, but the first file will remain unchanged as it is already less than 5 MiB in length. Read the command as "*truncate the file to* at most *5 MiB*".

Comment: so in a way, the `<` tells the tool to actually _truncate_ only, and never to _expand_. (I know the underlying system call is the same, but the common-sense meaning feels different to me.)

Comment: @ilkkachu yes. If you read `<` as the man page suggests as "_at most_" then the complementary action `>` can be read and understood as "_at least_". So `truncate --size '>5M' {file}` would ensure that both files were _at least_ 5 MiB in length.

Comment: So `truncate`  is a misleading name for the tool ;) truncate expands by default if the file is smaller! A better name would be `size-adjust`

Comment: 1/2 @rubo77 quite possibly, yes, although the name almost certainly comes from the corresponding [POSIX system call](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/truncate.html)

Comment: 2/2 I would imagine that the original tool was created to truncate a file but quickly people realised it actually set the file size (truncating or growing as necessary). I'd not come across `<`/`>` before yesterday despite it being in the GNU code as far back as [2008](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/commit/75e0047c4b916393b6be3cb985c4c4d4a2d1a836#diff-2a5541119011ef07785e32377b799a6c01e0c460a0a1197fd6fa0be1d5625391) though

Comment: Based on some old man pages from the FreeBSD man page archive, it looks like originally the system call only truncated, e.g. the [FreeBSD 2.0](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ftruncate&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+2.0-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) man page says "truncated to at most _length_ bytes" and has no mention of expanding. The Linux man page from Debian 2.2.7 says it's unspecified if a short file will be extended or not. In a way that makes sense, since you can always expand a file using regular writes so a separate system call for it is not needed.

Comment: @ilkkachu [This Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ftruncate.2.html) says it's extended. Also, writing zero-bytes might be inefficient; `truncate()` will generally make a sparse file very efficiently.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, the current ones do that, and even the POSIX spec says that. But considering the name doesn't really match the action of extending a file, it just occurred to me to wonder if there was a historical background to it. And indeed it looks like the name used to be more apt.

Comment: @ilkkachu Right. It may have originally been for shrinking files, when they added a way to extend a file they realized there would be no point in assigning a new name. A more appropriate name would be `setsize()`, but they didn't rename it.